# CR/LF condition check in C

Tags: c, tcp

I am testing my TCP echo server, with Telnet, I can see that the client connects to the server and sends a charcter and in return the server returns a string to the client.

Now my problem is by using this recv() in a infinite loop I can only receive one character (even though the client tends to send a string).

This is how I am doing to receive the datagram from the client

TCP SERVER

```
while(1)
{
    socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&client_address, (socklen_t)&client_length);

    recv(socket, recv_buffer, sizeof(recv_buffer), 0);
    printf("Received string from client is %s", recv_buffer);

    /*then I send my string to the client*/
    send(socket, send_buffer, sizeof(send_buffer), 0);
}
```

Here is my problem that my recv() routine reads only one character even though the client wants to send a whole string. Is there a way how I can make this recv() routine wait before it receives all the characters from the client and then send a response to the client.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Regards

Comment: As a side issue... it's worth noting that Telnet is a terminal client, so it's going to transmit more than just the string you type into it across to your server, so don't be suprised if you get some control codes which might at first glance appear to be garbage...

Comment: my problem is that I receive only one character even though the client sends me a complete string which is, I am typing on the telnet client manually. As soon as i type a letter it is received by ma server and my server sends a text which can been seen on the terminal output of the telnet.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are doing something wrong. Look at the definition of `recv`:

```
int recv(int s, void *buf, size_t len, int flags);
```

So it recieves `len` amount of bytes. You passed `sizeof(recv_buffer)` as the len parameter. Now I'm guessing `recv_buffer` is defined as  a `char*`. Getting the `sizeof`  of a pointer means that you get the amount of bytes necessary to store that pointer, instead of the memory it points to.

Do something like this instead:

```
const int buf_len = 100;
char recv_buffer[buf_len];

recv(socket, recv_buffer, buf_len, 0);
printf("Received string from client is %s", recv_buffer);
```

Comment: Won't work in general - there is no guarantee the string can be received with a single call to recv().

Comment: @unapersson: True, but complicates the story. The issue was taking the `sizeof` of a pointer.

Comment: I have tired the way you have suggested, but still its the same result

Answer (score 1):

You need to build up the string you are receiving yourself in a loop, using the return value of `recv()` to find how many bytes you actually got. TCP/IP does not guarantee that all the data sent with one call to `send()` can be received with one call to `recv()`. And you must examine the return value of every sockets function you call to check for actual lengths sent/received, and for errors.

Comment: I have checked the return value of recv(), and it shows me '1', that means as soon as I receive a character my send() function evokes and sends a string.

Comment: @Devb You have to keep calling recv until you receive all the characters you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a disaster (sorry for being blunt, but it is best to be straight).

recv() returns the number of bytes actually read.  Not only that but it will not clear the previous contents of the buffer and it will fill up right to the the end of the buffer if there is data available.  All this means that you cannot treat the content of the buffer as a null terminated string.

You need to do something like:

```
ssize_t bytesRead = 1;
char recv_buffer[SOME_SIZE];

while (bytesRead > 0)
{
    int bytesRead = recv(socket, recv_buffer, SOME_SIZE, 0);
    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        // do something with the bytes.  Note you cannot guarantee that the buffer contains a valid C string.
    }    
}
if (bytesRead == -1)
{
    // report error from errno
}
else
{
    // bytesRead == 0 have reached end of file (i.e. socket closed at other end)
}
```

There is no way to get recv to wait until the buffer is full before returning.  It will wait until there are some bytes available and then return.  The same applies to send by the way.  You can't assume with one call to send that all of your bytes have actually been sent.  You need to put send in a loop too:

```
ssize_t totalBytesWritten = 0;
ssize_t bytesWritten = 0;
while (bytesWritten >= 0 && totalBytesWritten < bytesToWrite)
{
    bytesWritten = send(socket, sendBuffer + totalBytesWritten, bytesToWrite - totalBytesWritten, 0);
    if (bytesWritten > 0)
    {
        totalBytesWritten += bytesWritten;
    }
}
if (bytesWritten == -1)
{
    // error
}
```

Comment: I need to say that after following your advice I still cannot get the desired output, for send it is working fine with my old code. I am still having no idea